# Button not showing up on Activity that opens from Fragment,but button shows up in Graphical Layout

Tags: java, xml, android-activity, android-fragments, android-button

I have created fragments(6 fragment) in my app.In my first fragment(android_frag) there is a button "Show Places on Map". When I click on that button new activity names "ShowPlaces" opens up. In the show_places xml file I have created one button that should return me to the previous screen i.e the android fragment but button is not showing up in when the ShowPlaces activity opnes up, though I can see the button in graphical layout of the xml file. I have not been able to find out where the problem is.Please help.

Here is my show_places.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<!-- Show on Map button -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_show_map1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="@string/showplaces"
     />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the ShowPlaces.java file

```
package com.example.tabswipe;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class ShowPlaces extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View ios = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_places, container, false);



      Button button = (Button) ios.findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);
           button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {    @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                    // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
                    // e.g. launch a new activity
              Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.tabswipe.Android");
                  startActivity(openStartingPoint);

                }
           }); 
           return ios;


   }


 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }





  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have android:id="@+id/btn_show_map1" in the xml but are trying to find the id btn_show_map.  These one should be changed to be the same as the other.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply...ya..It is like that only..typing error while posting the question